# Plotting a condition function in three dimensional space with Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, if-statement, plot

Problem: I want to plot a two varibles condition function f(x,y) on three dimesional space and here is my code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
if (0<y**2) == True and (y**2<x) == True: 
 z = 3/4
elif (y == 0) == True or (0<=x<=y**2) == True: 
 z = 0
plt.plot(x,y,z)
```

I type this code on Google Colab and it send me an error at line 3 as following

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `0 < y**2` is a boolean array and you're comparing it to a single value (`True`); that's where that error comes from.

When dealing with conditional values like this, its best to use [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) with NumPy:

```py
z = np.zeros(200)
z[(0 < y ** 2) & (y ** 2 < x)] = 3 / 4
```

By the way, in order to use 3D plots you should take a look at the [mplot3d Toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html):

[image]

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
z = np.zeros(200)

z[(0 < y ** 2) & (y ** 2 < x)] = 3 / 4

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
ax.plot(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```